# Protect ASP.NET API with IdentityServer & Bearer

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, bearer-token

I have a 3 tier application, where I have:

- A blazor web application
- a HTTP API
- An Identity Server

Currently, I have 2 kinds of controllers on the HTTP API:

- general-purpose API: can be accessed without authentication, but only if the call comes from the Web Application
- personal purpose API: can be accessed only after authentication

Right now, the "personal purpose API" working fine. this API is only accessible when the user is logged in.

But, I also need to protect the "general-purpose API" from any hacker, right now a call to "post/list" returns an "unauthorized error"!

I wish to protect this API, without authentication, but it must be only accessible from my web application.

Do you know how can I do this? Is there something wrong or missing in my code?

Here is the controller code on the HTTP API side :

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("post/list")]
        public async Task<List<Item>> GetListAsync()
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

Here is my code on the HTTP API side :

```
context.Services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
  options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
  options.ApiName = "SoCloze";
});
```

And here is my code on the Web Application side:

```
context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(ApplicationConstants.LoginCookieExpirationDelay);
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

            options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("role");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("phone");
            options.Scope.Add("SoCloze");

            options.ClaimActions.MapAbpClaimTypes();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the API simple, you of course want to only accept tokens from the trusted IdentityServer.

So basically you need a **generic access token** that is secure, but not tied to any human user. You could have the web app to request an access token using the client credentials flow and then use that token all the time when you want to access the API as a non-authenticated user.

In IdentityServer you would setup a separate client just for this.

Also using the IdentityModel library could help you out here (as a Worker Applications) https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/worker.html

see also https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/requesting/

This picture shows what I mean:

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is a SPA, how can you do a Client Credentials without compromising the client secret from client browser?

Comment: I would for my SPA application create a BFF and handle all of this in the backend and only use cookies between the SPA and BFF , see https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFPGOvDrTOk&ab_channel=Devoxx

Comment: BFF with Cookies in browser needs authentication of the user. You have the same problem.

Comment: I mean that your backend can get the access token for non-logged in users as well. See my updated picture in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should make your controller anonymous. With your configuration simply remove your Authorize attribute from your controller. If you had applied a global policy you'd need to add the anonymous attribute to your controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I guess you want cross-site protection. That is, you want to limit certain endpoints from being accessed only from the origin of your blazor app.

You need to trust in the client browser for [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The same origin policy controls interactions between two different origins. [Cross-origin writes are typically allowed, Cross-origin embedding is typically allowed and Cross-origin reads are typically disallowed, but read access is often leaked by embedding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access).

This protection is only for XHR calls from your browser and it doesn't protect againts direct access (postman, fiddler, any http client...).

To prevent cross-origin writes in your posts you can use Antiforgery tokens. [Asp Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0) create this tokens automatically if you specify POST in your forms:

```
<form asp-controller="Todo" asp-action="Create" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Todo"))
{
    ...
}
```

This will reject any post from any form that has not been previously loaded from your server.

Comment: Thanks, but I try to have protection from direct access, ie. postman etc... if I use anonymous, I can call with postman without token and it works! You see ?

Comment: Then you necessarily need some kind of authentication. Or what do you mean by "can be accessed without authentication, but only if the call comes from the Web Application"? I understand that you need to access from your client application, i.e. your browser, to your API, isn't it?

Comment: by example, if I have an eCommerce, the API that provide the list of product is only accessible by my web application, and not by Postman or whatever. But the API to order is only accessible to authenticated users. Now I have the second, but I also wish the first one, you see? I do not want that any application, hacker etc... call my "list of product API" without any token.

Comment: From what you say in the first case the information is in fact public, that is, I can access it without any authentication from the browser. I don't see any problem if anyone can extract that information one way or another, even from postman. At some point you have to open your api to the world to be consumed. On the other hand, if you consider that the information is not public then you have to authenticate the user.